# Turn on background color when highlighting with C-SPC on a mac?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm using emacs on a macbook. In linux, when I use C-SPC to start mark blocks, the area I marked has a yellowish background that tells me where I start & end. However, in my macbook the background is not highlighted, leaving me lost where the marked area is precisely sometimes. Can anyone tell me how to turn on the background color highlighting on a macbook?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do `M-x transient-mark-mode` to toggle the highlighting.

If you want it on by default, you can add `(setq transient-mark-mode t)` to your .emacs file.